# Can LAmbda layer have trainable parameters?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

my question is about the Lambda layer. From what I understand when using a lambda layer it can not hold weights/trainable parameters. But here in [this example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/examples/lstm/TensorFlowLite_LSTM_Keras_Tutorial.ipynb#scrollTo=wiYZoDlC5SEJ) the Lambda layer still has trainable paramaters (about 55k). How come this works here?

Comment: the lambda layer consists of one or more LTSM layers

Answer (score 0):

A Lamdba Layer is just a wrapper. It wraps any expression so that it can be used as a Layer. This wrapping does not lead to (trainable) parameters. E.g., if you want to perform a calculation on your input (like scaling it by a factor or subtracting the mean, etc), you describe it as a function, wrap it in a Lambda Layer and that's it. No extra parameters are necessary for the wrapping.

However, such an expression can also be passing your input through other keras layers. If you wrap entire layers like that, the wrapped layers then can have parameters themselves and still have when they are being wrapped.

Note that the wrapping in your example seems to be done to include the non-keras tf code. An alternative would have been to create a new subclass of `tf.keras.layers.Layer` and making the tf-specific things when implementing its `call` method and/or just using the functional model API.

Comment: Exactly.  The TF layers are composed of calculated preambles.

Comment: Ok thats also what I thought. But I tried this https://pastebin.com/VaEnrysi out and I  don't get any trainable parameters from my Lambda layer. Any clue? Its driving me crazy